# Objective C - Printing full view is trimming off content from right while using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext, uiprintinfo

I am printing my screen view which is currently being displayed on `iPhone` as below. But for some reason some part of the screen is trimming off, Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with below code

Note : I am using `autolayout` on my `view`. Screen shots are attached.

```
-(void)printItem {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if(printController ) {

        printController.delegate = self;

        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = @"resultado";
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        printController.printInfo = printInfo;
        printController.showsPageRange = YES;
        printController.printingItem = newImage;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
            }
        };

        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

    }
}
```

Simulator View 
[image]

Print View ( content trimming off )

[image]

Comment: Workaround :- Unchecked or Removed Size Classes from the storyboard works fine. Does any one know why does size clases is making this content to trim off ?

Comment: When are you calling `printItem`?  You might need a `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` before you render it to get the image.

Comment: This is not working.